Excel VBA High CPU usage
I have an Excel VBA program with a user form. The user form has two command buttons, one is to sort and the other is quit. When I put a break on the End Sub statement if the CmdSort_Click(), and hit F8 to complete the sub routine, my cpu usage is about 1%-3% for Excel. I know the break stops code execution.
When I remove the break and let the program run on it's own, the cpu usage jumps up to 50%-60%. What code is it executing at this point that makes the cpu usage so high and how do I fix it?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.
I am a little baffled as to what my program is doing while waiting for another action on the userform.
Variables not dimensioned below are public variables from the parent subroutine.
Private Sub CmdSort_Click()

'Sample of data contained in variables:

'DataRange = "A4:F1000"
'First = "A5"
'Second = "B5"
'Third = "C5"
'Fourth = "D5"
'Fifth = "E5"
'Sixth = "F5"
'SheetName = "Quartz Colors"

    Dim LastRow As Integer, A As Integer, ws As Worksheet, ref, firstRef As Boolean, FirstSort As String, SecondSort As String, _
        ThirdSort As String, FourthSort As String, FifthSort As String, SixthSort As String, B As Integer, FirstCol As String, _
    LastCol As String, FirstFound As Boolean

    If cboManufacturer.value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("You must select a manufacturer before you can sort")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FirstSort = ""
    SecondSort = ""
    ThirdSort = ""
    FourthSort = ""
    FifthSort = ""
    SixthSort = ""
    FirstCol = ""
    LastCol = ""
    FirstFound = False

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ws.Visible = True
    ws.Select

    LastRow = ws.Range(DataRange).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp).Row

    For A = Len(DataRange) To 1 Step -1
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(DataRange, A, 1)) Then
            DataRange = Left(DataRange, A) & Trim(Str(LastRow))   'Finds the datarange to sort
            Exit For
        End If
    Next A

    For A = 1 To Len(DataRange)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(DataRange, A, 1)) And Not FirstFound Then                  'Gets the letters of the first column
            FirstCol = Left(DataRange, A - 1)
            FirstFound = True
        End If
        If Mid(DataRange, A, 1) = ":" Then
            For B = A + 1 To Len(DataRange)
                If IsNumeric(Mid(DataRange, B, 1)) Then
                    LastCol = Mid(DataRange, A + 1, B - A - 1)                      'Gets the letters of the last column
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next B
            Exit For
        End If
    Next A

    ws.Range(DataRange).Select
                                'The below Case statements get the sort order for the various columns
    If SolidSurface Then
        Sixth = ""
        Select Case TextBox1.value
            Case Is = "1"
                FirstSort = First
            Case Is = "2"
                SecondSort = First
            Case Is = "3"
                ThirdSort = First
            Case Is = "4"
                FourthSort = First
            Case Is = "5"
                FifthSort = First
        End Select
        Select Case TextBox2.value
            Case Is = "1"
                FirstSort = Second
            Case Is = "2"
                SecondSort = Second
            Case Is = "3"
                ThirdSort = Second
            Case Is = "4"
                FourthSort = Second
            Case Is = "5"
                FifthSort = Second
        End Select
        Select Case TextBox3.value
            Case Is = "1"
                FirstSort = Third
            Case Is = "2"
                SecondSort = Third
            Case Is = "3"
                ThirdSort = Third
            Case Is = "4"
                FourthSort = Third
            Case Is = "5"
                FifthSort = Third
        End Select
        Select Case TextBox4.value
            Case Is = "1"
                FirstSort = Fourth
            Case Is = "2"
                SecondSort = Fourth
            Case Is = "3"
                ThirdSort = Fourth
            Case Is = "4"
                FourthSort = Fourth
            Case Is = "5"
                FifthSort = Fourth
        End Select
        Select Case TextBox5.value
            Case Is = "1"
                FirstSort = Fifth
            Case Is = "2"
                SecondSort = Fifth
            Case Is = "3"
                ThirdSort = Fifth
            Case Is = "4"
                FourthSort = Fifth
            Case Is = "5"
                FifthSort = Fifth
        End Select
    Else
        Select Case TextBox1.value
            Case Is = "1"
                FirstSort = First
            Case Is = "2"
                SecondSort = First
            Case Is = "3"
                ThirdSort = First
            Case Is = "4"
                FourthSort = First
            Case Is = "5"
                FifthSort = First
            Case Is = "6"
                SixthSort = First
        End Select
        Select Case TextBox2.value
            Case Is = "1"
                FirstSort = Second
            Case Is = "2"
                SecondSort = Second
            Case Is = "3"
                ThirdSort = Second
            Case Is = "4"
                FourthSort = Second
            Case Is = "5"
                FifthSort = Second
            Case Is = "6"
                SixthSort = Second
        End Select
        Select Case TextBox3.value
            Case Is = "1"
                FirstSort = Third
            Case Is = "2"
                SecondSort = Third
            Case Is = "3"
                ThirdSort = Third
            Case Is = "4"
                FourthSort = Third
            Case Is = "5"
                FifthSort = Third
            Case Is = "6"
                SixthSort = Third
        End Select
        Select Case TextBox4.value
            Case Is = "1"
                FirstSort = Fourth
            Case Is = "2"
                SecondSort = Fourth
            Case Is = "3"
                ThirdSort = Fourth
            Case Is = "4"
                FourthSort = Fourth
            Case Is = "5"
                FifthSort = Fourth
            Case Is = "6"
                SixthSort = Fourth
        End Select
        Select Case TextBox5.value
            Case Is = "1"
                FirstSort = Fifth
            Case Is = "2"
                SecondSort = Fifth
            Case Is = "3"
                ThirdSort = Fifth
            Case Is = "4"
                FourthSort = Fifth
            Case Is = "5"
                FifthSort = Fifth
            Case Is = "6"
                SixthSort = Fifth
        End Select
        Select Case TextBox6.value
            Case Is = "1"
                FirstSort = Sixth
            Case Is = "2"
                SecondSort = Sixth
            Case Is = "3"
                ThirdSort = Sixth
            Case Is = "4"
                FourthSort = Sixth
            Case Is = "5"
                FifthSort = Sixth
            Case Is = "6"
                SixthSort = Sixth
        End Select
    End If

    ' The below loop sorts the current Data Range according to the current sort criteria

    With ws.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        firstRef = True 'flag for checking if the first range is being checked...
        'loop over the range references
        For Each ref In Array(FirstSort, SecondSort, ThirdSort, FourthSort, FifthSort, SixthSort)
            If IsNumeric(Right(ref, 1)) Then
                If ref = FirstSort Then
                    .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range(ref), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal                       ' Brings 'Actives' to the top with xlDescending
                Else
                    .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range(ref), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                        order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal                        'Sorts all others as xlAscending
                End If
            Else
                If firstRef Then 'at least one sort criteria is needed
                    MsgBox "You must select sort criteria"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
            firstRef = False 'unset flag
        Next ref
        .SetRange ws.Range(DataRange)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With

    For A = 5 To LastRow                            ' Determine how many active rows there are
        If ws.Range(Left(Fourth, Len(Fourth) - 1) & A).value = "NO" Then
            B = A - 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next A

    With ColorList                                  'Populate the list with the current colors
        .ColumnCount = 6
        .ColumnWidths = "150 pt;110 pt;49.95 pt;49.95 pt;70 pt;70 pt"
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .RowSource = ws.Range(FirstCol & "5:" & LastCol & Trim(Str(B))).address
    End With

End Sub


The use of Case/Select over IF/then is a bit faster, but I wonder if there is a way to put all of this logic into a for/next / array to make it even more efficient?  Also you will need to put some sort of timer into the script so you can get the "slow" value to compare against as you work to refine the formula.

easleyfixed, Thanks for your thoughts.  Any thoughts on why the break at the end of the sub would cause it to run correctly?  Doesn't that mean that the program is doing something else after it processes the end sub statement?

This morning, the program is running perfectly with very little cpu usage.  I am beginning to suspect network issues for the problem.  Perhaps a temp file to the local computer that is later updated to the network drive is the solution.  I still wish I knew what was using all that cpu power.

Isn't this question better suited for the code review? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/
